# INSTALLSHIELD setup User may search for their personal or business logo and apply

Tags: wpf, installshield

Every windows screen in our WPF application displays the ICON in the upper left corner. Numerous users of this program have the expectation of seeing their company logo.

We made the logo.ico file a "always copy" so that it is copied into the bin location along with every build. ICON is referring to the logo.ico file in this case.

The logo.ico file's icon will be reflected on the Windows screen if we go ahead and replace it with any other image.

We cannot expect the customers to accomplish this, so we must make it easier for them to browse the icon file during installation. InstalledShield software is used to prepare the installation setup. If there is a better way, please describe it here. I seek advice on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes. During installation, user could be asked to browse and you can validate for required resolution and file extension. This option should also be given during install modify option so that icon could be changed even after installation.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to check why the icon is getting reflected if you replace it with any other image, windows has some specification on the image size to display the icon/tile on the screen. See whether your icon is meeting all those specification to reflect it on the screen.
https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/IHelpMarsShortcutProperties.htm#ref-views_3737199233_1323863
you can also find information regarding the icon specification from the Microsoft documentation pages.

Apart from that, if you want to show up a browse dialog during the installation then you need to modify your InstallShield project:
1- To launch a browse dialog from the Basic MSI project:
https://docs.revenera.com/installshield23helplib/helplibrary/FileOpenDialog-HowTo.htm
2- To launch a browse dialog from an InstallScript project:
https://community.flexera.com/t5/InstallShield-Knowledge-Base/Displaying-a-File-Browse-Dialog-in-an-InstallScript-Project/ta-p/3964

But, my preference to you to check why the icon is getting reflected if its replaced with other image, and fix it.